# Limit checkbox checked by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done the code mostly, just stuck on one little thing. If someone can help me please, as Jquery is really new to me. I just want to disable the remaining checkboxes when two checkboxes are checked. Below is the code,everything works great, just cant limit the checkboxes to disable when two are checked. So out of the list, I should only be able to check two.

Please check Live demo url for clearer understanding
http://www.babaraliseehar.com/onepage/index.php
Click on compare button to show the modal where I want the checkboxes functionality.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
        $('.modal')
            .prop('class', 'modal fade') // revert to default
            .addClass( $(this).data('direction') );
        $('.modal').modal('show');
    });
    
    
    
    
    $("#answers-type1 li").click(function() {
         // $(this).css("background-color","#27B249");
        // if ($("#answers-type1 li.place").length < 2 || $(this).hasClass('place')) {
             $( this ).toggleClass( "place" );
         //$( this ).toggleClass( "place" );
    
    
       
    });
    
    
    
    
     $('ul.myclass li').click( function() {
       var $cb = $(this).find(":checkbox");
        if (!$cb.prop("checked")) {
            $cb.prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $cb.prop("checked", false);
        }
    
    
        if($( ".number:checked" ).length == 2 && $( ".number:checked" ).length < 3)
      {
    
       $('#btn').prop('disabled', false);
      }
      else
      {
       $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
      } 
    
    
     });
```

```css
.myclass li span {
  margin-left: 5px;   
}

.place { 
 background-color: #27B249 !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 15%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="font-size: 18px;text-align: center;background-color: red;">
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: #fff;" >Compare Products</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="font-size: 16px">
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
    <ul id="answers-type1" class="myclass"  style="list-style: none;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
     <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Listol"><input name="listol"  type="checkbox" value="Listol" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Listol</span></li>
     <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Synaptal"><input name="synaptal"  type="checkbox" value="Synaptal" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Synaptal</span></li>
     <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Synaptal"><input name="focus_formula"  type="checkbox" value="Focus Formula" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Focus Formula</span></li>
     <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Bright Spark"><input name="bright_spark"  type="checkbox" class="number" value="Bright Spark" style="display: none;"><span>Bright Spark</span></li>
     <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Triple Complex"><input name="triple_complex"  type="checkbox" class="number" value="Triple Complex" style="display: none;"><span>Triple Complex</span></li>
    </ul>
   
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default clos" data-dismiss="modal" data-direction='left'>Cancel</button>
        <input  type="submit" id ="btn" value="Compare" name="submit" class="btn btn-success compare" disabled>
    </form>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: please add proper html your html is all buggy there is on form and 2 `</form>` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the check

```
 if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 2) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('place')) {
      return;
    }
  }
```

inside the

```
$('ul.myclass li').click(function() {
```

It will make sure you cant select more than 2 but at the same time allow you to un-select any of the selected.

See demo below

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.modal')
    .prop('class', 'modal fade') // revert to default
    .addClass($(this).data('direction'));
  $('.modal').modal('show');
});

$('ul.myclass li').click(function() {
  if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 2) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('place')) {
      return;
    }
  }

  var $cb = $(this).find(":checkbox");
  if (!$cb.prop("checked")) {
    $cb.prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $cb.prop("checked", false);
  }
  if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 2) {
    $('#btn').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);

  }


  $(this).toggleClass("place");





});
```

```css
.myclass li span {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.place {
  background-color: #27B249 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 15%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="font-size: 18px;text-align: center;background-color: red;">
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: #fff;">Compare Products</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="font-size: 16px">
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
          <ul id="answers-type1" class="myclass" style="list-style: none;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
            <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Listol"><input name="listol" type="checkbox" value="Listol" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Listol</span></li>
            <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Synaptal"><input name="synaptal" type="checkbox" value="Synaptal" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Synaptal</span></li>
            <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Synaptal"><input name="focus_formula" type="checkbox" value="Focus Formula" class="number" style="display: none;"><span>Focus Formula</span></li>
            <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Bright Spark"><input name="bright_spark" type="checkbox" class="number" value="Bright Spark" style="display: none;"><span>Bright Spark</span></li>
            <li class="module" style="background: #668693;" value="Triple Complex"><input name="triple_complex" type="checkbox" class="number" value="Triple Complex" style="display: none;"><span>Triple Complex</span></li>
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default clos" data-dismiss="modal" data-direction='left'>Cancel</button>
        <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Compare" name="submit" class="btn btn-success compare" disabled>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: You are awesome... Thanks alot